# Backbone create does not wait for json to be passed (Guid is undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

In a project i recently changed from using myVar[0].Key; to using myVar.WhatEver;
This messed up something, because now my .create does not wait for the request to be responded by the webservice, which means that variables like 'Guid', and in my case also 'Name', is not passed to the template when i try to render the created post.

My code (some what modified; the variable names does not match with original code):

```
var self = this;
var variableNames = this.options.variableNames;
variableNames.create({
            variable1: values.variable1,
            variable2: values.variable2,
            variable3: values.variable3 //And so on...
        }, {
            wait: true,
            success: function(variableName) {
                // Update nav menu list
                $('#nav').someJqueryMagic()
                      .text(variableName.get('Name'))
                      .data('variableName', variableName.get('Guid')) //This does not work. It is undefined by some reason!
                )); //This code adds a menu item

                //Call function for triggering the custom event, pass in the variableName object
                self.createSuccess(variableName);

                self.modal.close();
                new Interface.Message().success('OK! Du har skapat ett nytt objekt.'); //Swedish rules
            },
            error: function() {
                new Interface.Message().error('Det gick inte att skapa objektet.');
            }
        });
    },
    createSuccess: function(variableName) {
        //Trigger event for rendering the new entry
        this.vent.trigger('variableName:created', variableName);

        //This ends up with a table row is rendered. The variableName 
        //object contains Name of who has created the post, a Guid, and 
        //some other information.
    }
```

When I debug the code the request that is sent does not reply with the json object until the create is finished -> Too late i guess?
Any ideas of what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the backend code rather than in the frontend.
Somewhere in backend we triggered a 200 OK response to the request which in turn triggered the success of the .create().
I dont know where or how, but we fixed it by reverting some newly written code.